# cannot detect adb driver in windows server 2008 64 bit

Tags: android, adb

before, I use windows seven os for running the app on the device and it works.but when i try with windows server 2008 64 bit. the adb cant detect in my pc , and my project cant run in my device.

```
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platform-tools>adb de
vices
List of devices attached

D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platform-tools>
```

how adb device working correctly under Windows Server 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Android Debug Bridge (adb)  lets you communicate with an emulator instance or connected Android-powered device
Just go through this link and you will find the soluton:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html